# Removing certain characters from an url string (Python3)

Tags: python, string, url, urllib

I finally figured how to convert my dictionary with data into a string which gives me the desired output. I was wondering how to make this code more dense. Any suggestions?

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import re

#user input
start = '19851123'
end = '19851124'
stns = [('235','240')]
var = [('TEMP')]

#format input to dict
req = {
'start':start,
'end':end,
'vars':var,
'stns':stns
}

#format dict to url strg without modifing the 'safe characters'
q = urllib.parse.urlencode(req, doseq = True, safe="()',")

#removing the 'safe characters' and turn '+' into ':'
q = re.sub("[\(',\)]", "", q)
q = re.sub("\+", ":", q)

#combine the url and query
url = 'http://projects.knmi.nl/klimatologie/daggegeven/getdata_dag.cgi?%s' % q 


#create a handel with url+query
fhand = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

#print requested data whitout header
for line in fhand:
    if not line.decode().startswith('#'):
        print(line.decode().strip())
```

Comment: @JoeIddon Feel free to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: @SamOnela Ok thanks for the comment. I don't normally close for code review but felt this question was much more on topic for that SE. In future I will close for *primarily opinion based* then since I agree that is a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By preprocessing your `req` input, you could avoid the need for `re`:

```
req = {
  'start': 19851123,
  'end': 19851124,
  'vars': ['TEMP'],
  'stns': ['235:240'],
}

urllib.parse.urlencode(req, doseq=True, safe=':')
# 'start=19851123&end=19851124&vars=TEMP&stns=235:240'
```

So you could limit your code to:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import urlopen


def main(parameters, url='http://projects.knmi.nl/klimatologie/daggegeven/getdata_dag.cgi'):
    query = urlencode(parameters, doseq=True, safe=':')
    with urlopen('{}?{}'.format(url, query)) as fhand:
        for line in fhand:
            if not line.startswith(b'#'):
                yield line.decode().strip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    req = {
        'start': 19851123,
        'end': 19851124,
        'vars': ['TEMP'],
        'stns': ['235:240'],
    }
    for line in main(req):
        print(line)
```

But this feels cumbersome to modify the user input, so using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) might be beneficial. By the look of things, `vars` and `stns` could be of varying length so you might benefit from the [`'append'` action](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) with a specific default case handling:

```
import argparse
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import urlopen


def command_line_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('start', type=int)
    parser.add_argument('end', type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--vars', action='append')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--stns', action='append', nargs=2, type=int)
    return parser


def parse_command_line(parser):
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.vars is None:
        args.vars = ['TEMP']
    if args.stns is None:
        args.stns = [(235, 240)]
    args.stns = ['{}:{}'.format(*stn) for stn in args.stns]
    return args


def main(parameters, url='http://projects.knmi.nl/klimatologie/daggegeven/getdata_dag.cgi'):
    query = urlencode(parameters, doseq=True, safe=':')
    with urlopen('{}?{}'.format(url, query)) as fhand:
        for line in fhand:
            if not line.startswith(b'#'):
                yield line.decode().strip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for line in main(vars(parse_command_line(command_line_parser()))):
        print(line)
```

Usage being something like

```sh
$ python script.py -v TEMP -v TEST -s 235 240 19851123 19851124
```

which would query the following URL:

```
http://projects.knmi.nl/klimatologie/daggegeven/getdata_dag.cgi?start=19851123&end=19851124&vars=TEMP&vars=TEST&stns=235:240
```